# iPhone 12 mini screen parameters are unexpected

Tags: ios

Per the tech specs page, the screen is 2340 x 1080 pixels, but in the simulator (12.2 betas 3) it is 2436 x 1125.

screen parameters are unexpected: MGScreenClass1125x2436x3x495 SCREEN_TYPE(1125,2436,3,495)

Comment: I am seeing the same error. I am trying to run existing apps on a new iPhone 12 mini. When I ask the screensize it does not return the value expected based on the hardware spec. But anyway the code worked on the simulator but broke on the real phone. This message is not helpful or explanatory in any way.

Comment: Issue still exists with Xcode Version 12.3 RC (12C33) for both a new SwiftUI app and a new Swift Storyboard app with the iPhone 12 mini simulator.

Comment: 12/22/20 current simulator reports screen height of 2436. When I run real phone 12 mini under simulator the phone reports screen height of 2340. I cannot get the display on my phone to match the display on the simulator. Something is not working. My iPhone 12 is not in display zoom mode.

Comment: Any news and update on this? I'm building a TVOS app and getting this error when trying to display a video. Screen goes black, and that's it.

Comment: still happening in Xcode 12.4

Comment: Still present in Xcode 12.5

Comment: Still present in Xcode 12.5.1

Comment: Issue appears to be fixed with Xcode 13.  I was getting this error on 12.5.1 and I just decided to upgrade, and now finally after all these months the silly warning message has gone away!  Only thing is, Xcode is now giving me 55 warnings when I compile my app, whereas when I was running 12.5.1 I only had 3 warnings... so be warned....

Answer (score 9):

I am sure Apple will fix it soon, but for the moment for workaround
you can disable the logs 

Go and add to: 
Project > Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment Variables

Name: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE

Value: disable


This is not a solution it is only a very ***DANGEROUS*** workaround 
Dangerous like when it is active it hides all NSLogs from a real device and etc.

Enabling this option will allow you to read your own logs more clearly however you can miss other ***IMPORTANT ERROR MESSAGES*** since they might not appear

***SO USE IT CAREFULLY***

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Xcode 13, that seems to fix the issue...